# How to Unwrap a Modal class object in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, option-type, unwrap, forced-unwrapping

Model Class:

```
class CountryModel: NSObject {

    var name:NSString!

    var countryId:NSString!

    init(name: NSString, countryId: NSString) {
        self.name = name
        self.countryId = countryId
    }

}
```

ViewController:

```
var nameArr = [CountryModel]() // Model Class object

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = UITableViewCell()

        cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!

        let arr = nameArr[indexPath.row] // How to do if let here

        let str:String? = "\(arr.countryId) \(arr.name)"

        if let sstr = str{
            cell.textLabel?.text = sstr
        }

        return cell

    }
```

How should one unwrap this because output is an optional, if I try to unwrap **`nameArr[indexPath.row]`** gives an error **initializer for conditional binding must have optional type, not "country modal"**

It works fine I am not concatenating arr.countryId with arr.name

Comment: use `String` instead of `NSString` in modelClass and as CountryModal is not an optional .. it gives you that warning. No need to check optional there

Comment: @EICaptainv2.0 Thanks Sir, But after doing what you said it gives one optional"result here", Earlier there were two optional(Optional"value here")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works fine

```
        var nameArr = [CountryModal]()
        nameArr.append(CountryModal.init(name: "harshal", countryId: "india"))
        nameArr.append(CountryModal.init(name: "james", countryId: "australia"))

        let arr = nameArr[0]
        let str:String? = "\(arr.countryId!) \(arr.name!)" 
        if let sstr = str{
           print(sstr)
        }

        let arr2 = nameArr[1]
        let str2:String? = "\(arr2.countryId!) \(arr2.name!)"

        if let sstr2 = str2{
            print(sstr2)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks data in array is from a JSON, now arr2.name is still an optional, it says **Afghanistan Optional(1)**

Comment: Okay it done, i was getting an Int from JSON, so in initializer i took an Int type and then converted to string, it worked , thanks

Comment: That's a very strange example because you annotate an optional string constant (`String?`) but assign a 100% non-optional value, so the optional binding is meaningless. On the other hand the code crashes if `countryId` or `name` is `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this library https://github.com/T-Pham/NoOptionalInterpolation. It does exactly that

    `import NoOptionalInterpolation`

```
let n: Int? = 1
let t: String? = nil
let s: String? = "string1"
let o: String?? = "string2"

let i = "\(n) \(t) \(s) \(o)"
print(i) // 1  string1 string2
```

NoOptionalInterpolation gets rid of "Optional(...)" and "nil" in Swift's string interpolation. This library ensures that the text you set never ever includes that annoying additional "Optional(...)". You can also revert to the default behaviour when needed.

Also, please note that this does not affect the print function. Hence, print(o) (as opposed to print("(o)"), o as in the example above) would still print out Optional(Optional("string2"))

Comment: Interesting, but kindly explain it a bit more, what does there lines means

Comment: I have updated the post, I think that will help you. It's pretty simple and lightweight library. If you look at the implementation you can easily understand. It has Unwrappable protocol and extension of Optional that extract the optional value.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid forced unwrapping as much as possible. i.e. using '!'. Whenever you see !, try and think of it as code smell.

For json parsing you would not know for sure if the values for countryId and name exists or not. So, it makes sense to keep them as optionals and gracefully try to unwrap them later.

```
class CountryModel {

var name: String?
var countryId: String?

init(name: String?, countryId: String?) {
    self.name = name
    self.countryId = countryId
}

}

var nameArr = [CountryModel]()

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") else {
    fatalError("cell should always be initialised")
}

var str: String?

let arr = nameArr[indexPath.row] // How to do if let here

if let countryId = arr.countryId, let name = arr.name {
    str = "\(countryId) \(name)"
}

if let unwrappedString = str {
    cell.textLabel?.text = unwrappedString
}

return cell
}
```

Bonus:
You could simplify your json parsing a lot using the [Object Mapper](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) library. It simplifies a lot of your parsing logic.